# Why malloc can not allocate huge memory in FreeBSD-x64 kernel space?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, freebsd

I try to allocate large memory in FreeBSD-x64 kernel space, but it returns NULL.

```
  void *ptr = NULL;

  static int
  init_module(void)
  {
       u_long SIZE_ALLOC = ((u_long)2500 * 1024 * 1024);

       ptr = malloc(SIZE_ALLOC, M_DEVBUF, M_NOWAIT);

       if( !ptr )
       uprintf("Allocation has been failed!!\n");

       return (0);  
   }
```

I have enough `RAM(8 [GB]`) and I have enough free memory, but it returns `NULL`.

If I run this code in user-space it works fine and catch huge memory but for kernel-space it fails !!!!

Where is mistake and how can I solve this?

Comment: 64 bit process?  It's going to try to allocate a contiguous range of memory.  If there's fragmentation it'll fail even though in total it's got enough free when you add up all of the individual free spaces.

Comment: I think the upper cap of the kernel space need not necessarily match with your system's RAM space.Curious question ,why do you need to allocate that huge amount of memory?

Comment: @Robinson true, possibly its looking for a contiguous range of memory.

Comment: I need it for special memory pool.

Comment: Yes, I need contiguous range of memory. Why this works in user-space fine, but for kernel-space has problem? I have about 6 [GB] free space.

Comment: Per https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=malloc&sektion=9, use of `M_NOWAIT` will cause the `malloc()` to fail if the request can't be fulfilled immediately.  Do you have enough free memory to fulfill the request without doing things like dropping cache?

Comment: caveat: I'm on ubuntu linux 14.04.    according to the man page for malloc(), there is only one parameter,  so the posted code does not compile.

Comment: @user3629249 (Linux) user space is different from (FreeBSD) kernel space. As you can see in the link in Andrew Henle's comment, FreeBSD's *kernel* malloc does take three arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You can only get a NULL result when you use the `M_NOWAIT` flag.
It basically means that there is not this much memory available *right now*.

Try `M_WAITOK`. And I would add a `M_NODUMP` as well. The consequence is that the module init process might be put to sleep until enough memory is freed up.

The kernel *malloc* allocates *phyisical memory*, which is not paged. See the [memory management section](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/design-44bsd/overview-memory-management.html) in "The Design and Implementation of the 4.4BSD Operating System". The same text can be found verbatim in "The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System".

You can look at the amount of physical memory available with the `sysctl vm.phys_free`. On my machine this shows:

```
FREE LIST 0:

  ORDER (SIZE)  |  NUMBER
                |  POOL 0  |  POOL 1  |  POOL 2
--            -- --      -- --      -- --      --
  12 ( 16384K)  |       0  |       0  |       0
  11 (  8192K)  |       0  |       0  |       0
  10 (  4096K)  |       0  |       0  |       0
   9 (  2048K)  |       0  |       0  |       0
   8 (  1024K)  |       0  |       0  |       0
   7 (   512K)  |       0  |       0  |       0
   6 (   256K)  |       0  |       0  |       0
   5 (   128K)  |      33  |       4  |       0
   4 (    64K)  |    2137  |     112  |       0
   3 (    32K)  |   18136  |     116  |       5
   2 (    16K)  |   20492  |      47  |   11111
   1 (     8K)  |    2817  |      24  |   23422
   0 (     4K)  |    1396  |      32  |    4956
```

If I interpret this correctly, I could not allocate a contiguous block >128K using the kernel malloc.

Comment: I have check M_WAITOK but FreeBSD was paniced. I don't have any idea about M_NODUMP!!!!!

Comment: Then there is problably not enough memory to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

whatever RAM you have it does not increase the portion, in same proportion of huge RAM, of RAM used by kernel. Usually Kernel has 1GB RAM to use for its functionality (I am not much sure about definite amount). So due to limited available RAM, failure of such huge allocation in kernel mode is not a surprize

Comment: No, kernel dose not have any limitations. I think contiguous range of huge memory has problem in kernel-space.

Comment: contiguous range is definitely a  problem. in my view having very huge contiguous range  in kernel space is very difficult due to my knowledge of some limits on kernel space. you by yourself said in user space it gives success then why it is happening.